# Tutorials for making Android flash games

Tags: android, flash

I want to start creating Android flash games but can't find any tutorials, can anyone suggest any good tutorials?

Comment: [this one](http://tutorials101.blogspot.se/2011/02/android-game-development-creating.html) seems good